# receiving string literals and storing it in the integer column in the database

Tags: mysql, database, sendgrid

[Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) says that the Categories are in the form of String data type as follows:

```
[
  {
    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337966815,
    "category": [
      "newuser",
      "transactional"
    ],
    "event": "open"
  },
  {
    "email": "jane.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337966815,
    "category": "olduser"
    "event": "open"
  }
]
```

So, if someone sends a numerical number , say `11111` for category, sendgrid will treat it as a string and send it back .

I always use numerical values to send and when I get the same value back, I store it in an integer column in my database. For example I will be storing 
`11111` value in my column `category_int` and it's data type is `int(11)`.

Since, I am always storing it in an integer column, whenever someone sends category in the form of actual string just like above `olduser` , I get an error.

**My Question:**

Am I seeing error because,my `category_int` column is intended to receive integer values and not string values? But if this is true then, isn't the value that sendgrid is sending , in case of numbers(in my case 11111) is 
treated as string and perhaps, I should be getting error in this case as well. Where as I get errors only when I send category in the form of some descriptive words like `olduser`etc.

Please advise.

Comment: @Brand hits the answer to your question right on the head. However, you might want to ask if mySQL (or a relational database) is the right solution at all. The SendGrid event webhook provides unstructured data that changes based on events and as the webhook is updated (so schema'd columns aren't necessarily the best thing). I often recommend using a document store like MongoDB instead of a relational database for the webhook. However, this all depends on your implementation and maybe mySQL is right for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that an `int(11)` column cannot contain a string. MySQL is able to understand that "11111" as a string can be changed to the int `11111` and knows how to convert it. But it doesn't know how to make `olduser` into an int, so it throws an error.

You could change your data type to `varchar`, and then that column would be able to handle both `11111` and `olduser`.

You could also check the value in your code before you pass it to the database, and throw out values that cannot be made into ints.